# SAP GUI installation

Tags: java

i want to install SAP GUI but It shows the installation steps as broken, buttons do not appear, help me please

[image]

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.9-ea" 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9-ea+6-Ubuntu-1)
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9-ea+6-Ubuntu-1)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to ask ubuntu. Please also provide info on you GPU and drivers used.

Comment: Thank you so much, i installed ubuntu on vmware
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: SVGA II Adapter [15AD:405]
       vendor: VMware [15AD]
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=vmwgfx latency=64 resolution=1280,800
       resources: irq:18 ioport:d010(size=16) memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:f0000000-f01fffff memory:c0000-dfff

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/SR647wR57FBQ.png

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/AJP03PTqsjkv.png

Comment: I solved the problem by unchecking the option Enable 3D Acceleration

Comment: Nice to hear this, You could add that as an answer to your question and mark it as solved. So that other people can benefit in the future.